# cygwin command to copy to windows clipboard

Tags: cygwin

I see here:

http://www.pgrs.net/2008/1/11/command-line-clipboard-access

that there's a way in linux and osx to copy to the clipboard from the command line.  So I ran my cygwin setup.exe, but couldn't find the xsel package.  I'm guessing maybe this package hasn't been ported to windows?  Looks like there's a tool to do it in windows:

http://www.labnol.org/software/tutorials/copy-dos-command-line-output-clipboard-clip-exe/2506/

I guess I'll try that - but in the mean I figured I'd ask if anyone has found a good solution.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

On the page you linked, there are comments hinting how to do it on windows:

> On Windows, Cygwin comes with getclip
>   and putclip which do the same job.

Comment: If you don't have these available, you'll need to install the `cygutils-extra` package ([src](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2013-06/msg00503.html)). Interestingly [Babun](https://babun.github.io/) omits this package by default.

Answer (score 179):

Cygwin comes with special device file called [`/dev/clipboard`](http://williammitchell.blogspot.com/2008/03/fun-with-cygwins-devclipboard.html):

```
echo foobar > /dev/clipboard  # Puts "foobar\n" on the clipboard
cat /dev/clipboard  # Pastes clipboard to stdout
```

Comment: this works also, but I guess I can't accept 2 different answers

Comment: This is better than getclip/putclip, as it requires no package installation.

Comment: The advantage of getclip/putclip over /dev/clipboard is that the former have options to convert between unix and dos line endings.

Comment: The advantage of /dev/clipboard is that it supports UTF8, whereas getclip/putclip doesn't.

Comment: And it's easy to create `putclip` containing `cat - >/dev/clipboard` and `getclip` containing `cat /dev/clipboard` -- as aliases or functions or scripts, whichever takes your fancy.  You can use any pair of script names, of course.  Mac's have `pbcopy` and `pbpaste` to put and get information from the pasteboard (clipboard), for example.

Comment: /dev/clipboard is pretty gangster.

Answer (score 28):

I second the answer above

To cat text to the Windows clipboard

```
putclip < foo.txt
```

To pipe to a file whatever text is in the Windows clipboard

```
getclip > foo.txt
```

Comment: @Adrian Thanks for noticing my useless use of cat. I tend to overuse cat instead of just pipes. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 25):

getclip/putclip is found in cygutils-extra package.

Answer (score 13):

what about just

```
clip < file.extension
```

just tried in on my ssh key

Comment: `clip.exe` was introduced in Windows Vista, so yes, you can use that as well, but the options are limited.

Answer (score 2):

Actually [google "resource kit clip "](https://www.google.fi/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=download%20resource%20kit%20clip&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest#sclient=psy-ab&hl=fi&client=opera&hs=y8e&rls=en&channel=suggest&q=download%20resource%20kit%20tools%20clip&oq=download%20resource%20kit%20tools%20clip&gs_l=serp.3..33i21.13996.14645.0.15010.6.6.0.0.0.2.165.682.3j3.6.0...0.0...1c.2Ss5gWpByCc&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=f0e0fb357e063fcc&biw=1600&bih=870) for your windows clip and in cygwin terminal ( I use [puttycyg](http://code.google.com/p/puttycyg/downloads/list) works the following: 
find | clip

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly Ditto, but here's a clibboard logger.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
while true
do
    if [[ "$(</dev/clipboard)" = "${LastClip}" ]]
    then
            sleep 2
    else
            LastClip="$(</dev/clipboard)"
            echo "$(</dev/clipboard)" >> $HOME/cliplog.txt
            sleep 1
    fi
done
```